# How can I get the names of authors of books with the shortest titles from this database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's suppose I have a database with the following tables

```
authors (author_id TEXT, name TEXT)

books (isbn TEXT, publisher TEXT, title TEXT, publication_year INTEGER)

copies (copy_id INTEGER, isbn TEXT)

authorship (isbn TEXT, author_id INTEGER)

categories (category_id INTEGER, category_name TEXT)

in_category (isbn TEXT, category_id INTEGER)
```

And I want to get the names of authors of books with the shortest titles. I think I could take isbn numbers of books with the shortest titles, get the author_id and from this get the name.

I would be glad for any help with this problem.

Comment: show us what you did add some sample data , what SQL you wrote and what issue you faced. Please go through community guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's the problem? You already sketched the way...

```
SELECT
    b.title,
    a.name
FROM
    books b
JOIN authorship as ON b.isbn = as.isbn
JOIN authors a ON as.author_id = a.author_id
ORDER BY length(b.title)
LIMIT -- number of books you want
```

Comment: I understand this, but how to modify this to show only the titles of books with the shortest title? Let's say the books with the shortest titles all have titles of length n that is not given explicitly.

Comment: Okay, you can just change the ORDER BY length(b.title) with WHERE length(b.title) = (SELECT min(length(title)) FROM books) and delete the last line.